# objectID many to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectid

I need some help with my Swift rookie programming...

In a *many-to-many* relationship, I have a `NSManagedObjectID` that I`ve segued from another view controller.

To retrive data from it I have used this:

```
var elevid :NSManagedObjectID?

let person = context.object(with: studentId!)

nameTextField.text = person.value(forKey: "name") as? String
```

This works fine, but when I try to get an attribute from a relationship I`m stuck.

I´ve tried this:

```
let isAtSchool = person.value(forKeyPath: "isAtSchool.monday") as! Bool
```

but I get an error telling me:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectSetI' (0x10ac63aa8) to 'NSNumber' (0x109e5a4a8).

If I use `?` after as instead of `!` it returns `nil`.

Someone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you describe the nature of the relationship and any relevant attributes? Especially, what exactly is `isAtSchool` and what is `monday` here?

Comment: Hi! isAtSchool is an entity with a many-to-many relationship. monday is an attribute from this entity. The managedObjectId is  from a entity called "Students and is fetched with NSFetchedResultsController and segued from another viewController called "Pupils". Im trying to retrieve data and then update them, witch works fine when I use valueForKey, but not valueForKeyPath. Hope this clears up a little. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for the `name` property you're asking for a single value, so that's no problem. But when you're using this key path you're traversing a to-many relationship. There could be 2 or 10 or a million related objects, but you you're asking for a single `Bool`. How is that supposed to work?

It's not clear what you actually want in this situation. Of those potentially millions of related objects, how do you want to calculate the value of that `Bool`? *Probably* you want to do something like pick out a single related object out of those (potential) millions and get the `Bool` from that single instance. But for all I know you might want to scan over all of them and see what the most common `Bool` value is.

How to change your code depends on what you really need, how that single `Bool` value should be determined. One way or another you need to get from (potential) millions of related objects to a single `Bool`-- and you can't do that via a key path lookup.

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering. How can I use NSmanagedObject ID and get a single property from a to-many relationship? or maybe I can't do that? sorry for being unclear here. Its the best I can do so far :)